# KeyError 'PATH' on numpy Import

Tags: python, numpy

When importing numpy I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/Projects/Reinforcement-Learning/cardgame/reinforcement_learning_agent.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "/home/xxx/environments/machinelearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 126, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "/home/xxx/environments/machinelearning/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py", line 9, in <module>
    os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + extra_dll_dir
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PATH'
```

I can image that is has to do something with me working with a virutal environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that this is an issue which is already fixed but the fix is not released yet:

- [Issue in numpy github repo](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10338)
- [Pull request with fix](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/10339)

Until the fix is live I just implemented the fix as workaround in my code myself:

```
# before importing numpy add 'PATH' to os.environ
import os
os.environ.setdefault('PATH', '')
import numpy as np
```

Comment: This works to solve Key Error PATH missing for wsgi.py on Windows on App Engine as well.